# Stable analogues of type-changing struct update syntax

Tags: rust

##### Setup

Looking for the simplest solution while type-changing struct update syntax is unstable. I have the following structure:

```rust
struct A<T> {
  i1: i32,
  i2: i32,
  pd: PhantomData<T>,
  s: String,
}
```

###### Note

In reality, the struct has more fields and they have long meaningful names. Also, some of them have 3rd party types and/or represent some external resources (e.g. HTTPConnection, etc.).

##### The question

And I have to implement the function:

```rust
fn into_unit<T>(a: A<T>) -> A<()>;
```

What would be the simplest way to do that which wouldn't require me to repeat all the fields?

##### My attempt

Here is my attempt with `frunk`, but it requires some deciphering to understand, so it's not necessarily simpler than the bare destructing/constructing approach:

```rust
fn into_unit<T>(a: A<T>) -> A<()> {
    let a = frunk::into_labelled_generic(a);
    frunk::from_labelled_generic(hlist![field![_, PhantomData::<()>], ...a].sculpt().0)
}
```

Comment: If your types are compatible, [`zerocopy`](https://docs.rs/zerocopy/0.6.1/zerocopy/) offers a safe [`transmute`](https://docs.rs/zerocopy/0.6.1/zerocopy/macro.transmute.html).

Comment: Couldn't make it work easily, docs are very poor and don't work out of the box, not sure what I am doing wrong. Also, important thing is that struct fields are not intended to be serializable (there might be HTTPConnection, etc.).

Comment: I could be wrong but I think even when the type parameter is only used by a ZST, Rust doesn't guarantee that `A<T>` and `A<U>` have the same layout (they probably will but I can't find anything in writing), so I'm not sure a transmute could ever be safe. Is the struct changing a lot? Or does it have hundreds/thousands of fields? Otherwise I don't understand why writing it out once is so bad.

Comment: An easy solution is to create a private inner type with the invariant fields, something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a34c021769c5335ca4aab5fd7387bb92). It has the drawback of an additional struct level to access the inner fields.

Comment: I think the best stable solution is to just name all fields.

Comment: @isaactfa `zerocopy` requires that compatible types have a defined representation, e.g. `repr(C)`, `repr(transparent)` or `repr(packed)`. So it won't work if there may be more complex fields like `HTTPConnection`.

Comment: However it might be possible to write a macro that would generate an `impl<T> Into<A<()>> for A<T>` alongside the struct (or even an `impl<T, U> Into<A<U>> for A<T>` if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the struct definition in a macro that will generate the appropriate `into_unit` implementation:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

macro_rules! with_phantom_conversion {
    (struct $name:ident { $($field:ident: $type:ty),* $(,)?}) => {
        struct $name<T> {
            $($field: $type,)*
            pd: PhantomData<T>,
        }

        fn into_unit<T> (other: $name<T>) -> $name<()> {
           $name {
               $($field: other.$field,)*
               pd: PhantomData,
           }
        }
    }
}

with_phantom_conversion! {
    struct A {
        i1: i32,
        i2: i32,
        s: String,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: A<i32> = A { i1: 1, i2: 2, s: "foo".to_string(), pd: PhantomData, };
    let _b: A<()> = into_unit (a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=cadf90f7dd8e46abadb94ac32142e79a)